How to hide link to a different file in bottom left corner?
So i am making a proxy site, and i have a fontawesome button that links to a different file, but it shows in the bottom left corner of my screen when i hover over the button. Most of the current topics civer normal buttons, but they dont work for me since mine is fontawesome or smth...
Gif Demo
<a href="games.html" target="_blank"class="icon fa-solid fa-gamepad fa-hover"></a>
I looked through some of the problems related to this on the site, but none worked. Also I though that since it was a .html file it automatically wasnt going to show up.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Your problem is with the link showing in the bottom when you hover, am I getting this right ?

"Also I though that since it was a .html file it automatically wasnt going to show up." - were do you even come up with stuff like that ...? The browser status bar shows what a link points to. The browser doesn't even have any idea at this point, that this URL will indeed return an HTML document.

Do you mean the browser showing you the url to help prevent phishing attacks?  This applies to all <a href= which what you are using.  font-awesome is irrelevant (confirm by removing the fa- classes and adding some text).   To get around it, use a <button type='button' and some javascript to redirect (which will only work if js is enabled ofc)

@CBroe interesting, I read it as the current page was an html page rather than the link.  Still seems an unusual expectation either way.

What i meant is that when hovering over a button/hyperlink it shows what page its taking you to when you click on it in the bottom left of the screen. THAT IS BAD (for me). Im asking if there is some css/js/whatever that allows that link to be hidden sorry if the gif is bad quality.

@fdomn-m should i replace the a href= with the button type button?

do it with the click function and add window redirection.

THAT IS BAD (for me) why do you want to hide where a link takes you? THAT IS BAD (for everyone using your site)

@JaromandaX i meant bad for me making it becuase i didnt want it to be that way therefore its bad.

Still looks like you want to hide the link :p

@JaromandaX i do want to hide the link becuase i am making a school proxy site, and the school system can block the proxy if they know the link, also so no one can copy the link and use it for themselves.

OK, so how does the answer you accepted stop the school from blocking the site? I must not understand what you mean by "proxy" I guess

@JaromandaX it doesnt stop the,. it just lowers the chance that they will, eg they arent going to try to find the link to block it if its not avaiable, therefore it takes longer to get blocked, its kinda like a roadblock for them, so they have to take the long route

again, I misunderstand your usage of the word proxy - all you have is a link that opens in a new tab- any school site filter won't be fooled by a page opening in new tab

@JaromandaX lets just say... i know what to do, what im doing (for the most part), and how to do it... Im not even close to being done with the project.

With a little knowledge people can still open the browser developer tools and see the real URL that way (adding breakpoints, network tab, ...). Still seems like security by obscurity to me, even with your reasons given.

Showing the destination before you click it is no different from clicking the link then getting the destination from the address bar (except for opening yourself to the risks of nefarious websites), so hiding the browser popup is not a security concern (style/UX maybe, but never security).    <a href= could be grep'd for and blocked, but then so could any basic url regex be searched for / scarped for (not just href=), so again, no use for security.

the school system can block the proxy if they know the link - it's highly unlikely that anyone one is determining links to block by pointing at images on a random page and writing down the browser link tooltip!

While that might be true, my school system is just built different somehow...

You can hide it by using JS, something like this :


document.querySelectorAll('.icon').forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const href = this.getAttribute('data-href');
        if (href) {
            window.open(href, '_blank');
        }
    });
});
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-home icon" data-href="https://www.example.com/home">1</i>
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle icon" data-href="https://www.example.com/info">2</i>
    <i class="fas fa-envelope icon" data-href="https://www.example.com/contact">3</i>
</div>



